# Proper way to call env variables

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

I have written this code  in the server.js

```
 configDotenv = require("dotenv").config({ path: path.join(__dirname, "../.env") });
```

And I want to access the env variables in a different file example in this Test.js file

```
console.log(process.env.Name); it is throwing variable is undefined.
```

And if i log `console.log(process.env)` it is not showing me the env variables but other things in diffrent files.

Comment: Yeah, so basically `dotenv` looks for an `.env` file in the same path where ever u use the code. so in your case just verify if u are able to import with the path u have used. otherwise try changing the path and it'll work. rest seems fine

Comment: `Name` variable exist on your .env ? Just Name variable is being retrieved?